# Need help using ConfigurationManager from aspx page

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

New to ASP.NET. Trying to be able to switch what text is being displayed based off a value in the Web.config file. Here is a sample of my code.

```
<td background="images/LoginBox_03.gif" width="350" height="151">
                <table border="0" align="center" id="tblLogin" runat="server">
                    <tr id="trEmail" runat="server">
                        <%
                        If System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AD") <> "True" Then
                        %>
                        <td>
                            Email:
                        </td>
                        <%
                        ElseIf System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AD") = "False" Then
                        %>
                        <td>
                            Username:
                        </td>
                        <%
                        End If
                        %>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="145px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
```

Visual Studio doesnt like this for some reason. The code is not highlighted like it is actually code. More like it is just text. I do not think the VB.NET code is inserted correctly. Could someone help point out what is wrong here?

Comment: Does your code run?  Do not worry if the syntax highlighting is off, this is a problem of you inserting code in ASPX, where you should really try to keep your code in a code behind file as much as possible.

Comment: Code is often not highlighted in aspx pages for a variety of reasons.  Such as it hasn't done a behind the scenes compile yet, compilation errors, problems resolving references, etc.  In short don't trust the lack of syntax highlighting to mean anything.  What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Your syntax looks off a little too. You first check if it's not true, then you check if it is false. What happens if it is true? Your code doesn't account for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered moving the logic to the code behind file? It will clean up your page a little.

aspx:

```
<td background="images/LoginBox_03.gif" width="350" height="151">
                <table border="0" align="center" id="tblLogin" runat="server">
                    <tr id="trEmail" runat="server">
                        <td>
                            <asp:label id="lblFoo" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" Width="145px" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
```

Code behind:

```
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
If System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AD") <> "True" Then
         lblFoo.text = "UserName"
Else
         lblFoo.text = "Email"
End If


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using inline code as you have above, IMO, the better way is to use a`<asp:Label .../>` control.

The return values from `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AD")` is of type `String` you must first cast it to a `Boolean` then check the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can write fragments of code like this...

```
<tr>
    <%
    If X Then
        Response.Write "<td>blabla</td>"
    Else
        Response.Write "<td>omglol</td>"
    End If
    %>
</tr>
```

would work better I think.

I also noticed somthing strange in your `If...ElseIf` statement.

```
If System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AD") <> "True" Then
    'Happens if False.
ElseIf System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("AD") = "False" Then
    'Also happens if false
EndIf
```

Because if it is different than true, then it is false.